# Incorrect icon of Time Capsule in Finder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, time-capsule, icon

Have a little perfectionistic problem: quite often in Finder Time Capsule's icon not displayed correctly, when I click on it - becomes normal, what's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the bugs which Mavericks 10.9.4 has. So you can't do anything beside waiting and hoping, that apple will fix this issue in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

Also I have this problem in OS 10.10 Yosemite and it's continues to give me the inconvenience, so I googled till I find the answer. Finally, I'm trying to do this: make sure that the TC is not mounted (or dismount it). Then in finder menu use Go -> Connect to Server. Type AFP://TCnetworkname or IPaddress (replace with the real IP or real network name). When the computer finds the TC, you need to give a password (public for default) type in your password if you changed it or public if not, then save it in your keychain. That's it.